# Recursive PHP function doesn't stop and freezes my browser

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following recursive function:

```
$cogs = array('hello', 'how', 'are', 'you');

$wheels = array();

foreach($cogs as $cog)
{
    $wheels[] = array($cog);
}

function recursive($placement){
    $counter = count($placement);
    $nword = '';    
    for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
        $nword .= $placement[$i][0];
        echo $nword;
    }
    recursive($placement);
}

recursive($wheels);
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong as my function just keeps going. I cant figure out why… I am new to recursive functions in PHP so any help on a solution to this would be appreciated. What is the best way to have a safety net so my PHP function does not run forever for any recursive function?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't stop because `recursive` is an infinite loop. You've written:

```
function recursive($placement) {
    // Code that doesn't return, and outputs text
    recursive($placement);
}
```

Why do you expect that to ever terminate?

Any recursive function needs to have some condition that eventually will prove true and upon proving true will terminate the recursion.

Your browser is freezing because it likely is having a hard time with the massive amounts of output your PHP script has sent to it.

Most PHP installations will eventually terminate a script that has run for too long. However, as mentioned, your browser may have difficulties if it has to deal with a huge amount of output from the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a **stop condition**. In your function you print every time the same things (the first position of each vars in the array) and after that you call again the same function with the same input.